# Kotlin transformation of objects to another objects

Tags: android, json, kotlin

http://cm08323.tmweb.ru/android/determinace/json/images.json
I have some json to the server.

My database class:

```
@Entity
data class Image(val url: String = "", val urlAnswer: String = "", val race: String = "") : DisplayableItem, Persistable
```

Interface for api:

```
interface ImagesAdi {
    @GET("android/determinace/json/images.json")
    fun getImages(): Single<List<ImagesResponse>>
}
...
class ImagesResponse(
        val images: List<ImageSingle>)

class ImageSingle(val url: String,
            val url_answer: String,
            val race: String)
```

My mapper for transformation **ImagesResponse** to **Image**:

```
@Singleton
class ChooseRaceMapper @Inject constructor() : (ImageSingle) -> Image {
    override fun invoke(response: ImageSingle): Image = Image(response.url, response.url_answer, response.race)
}
```

How should look like transformer from **List< ImageSingle >** to **List< Image >**?

I have trasformer for single objects, he looks like that:

```
fun chooseRace(): Single<Image> = imagesAdi.getSingleImage()
        .map { chooseRaceMapper.invoke(it) }
        .doOnSuccess {
            database.addDetectedResult(it)
                    .subscribeIgnoreResult()

            requestImages()
        }
```

Can you help me to write transformer for type "**List**"? I trying make it, but  it did not work out. Thanks. Sorry for my English.

Or transformation from List to List should be better in class Mapper? (In method invoke)

Comment: Well, you have a list of images, but you only need a single one. I guess you just need to pick one in the list. Which one do you want?

Comment: @marstran I need to transformation objects from List<ImageSingle> to List<Image> and the function chooseRace return list type of Single<List<Image>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering your *images.json*, your `getImages()` should not return a `Single` of a `List`.

```
@GET("android/determinace/json/images.json")
fun getImages(): Single<ImagesResponse>
```

Then you could use the Kotlin [`List.map()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) mapper to map the list.

```
imagesAdi.getImages()
    .map { list -> list.map { chooseRaceMapper.invoke(it) } }
    .doOnSuccess { }
```

Answer (score 1):

The interface declaration is wrong:

```
interface ImagesAdi {
    @GET("android/determinace/json/images.json")
    fun getImages(): Single<List<ImagesResponse>>
}
```

It should be (according to your json):

```
interface ImagesAdi {
    @GET("android/determinace/json/images.json")
    fun getImages(): Single<ImagesResponse>
}
```

And for the mapping part, something like this will do:

```
imagesAdi.getImages().map { it.images }
    .map { /* your mapper here */ }
    ...
```